# Airflow Python TypeError: cannot deepcopy this pattern object

Tags: python, python-2.7, airflow

I am using Airflow with Python 2.7, I tried to clear the Airflow tasks and rerun some of them, when I hit clear, I got the following error. For the task in other DAG it works fine. Does anyone know what's going on here and can provide their suggestions, thanks!

```
Most Recent Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 174, in deepcopy
    y = copier(memo)
TypeError: cannot deepcopy this pattern object
```

Comment: I found the issue is actually with one of the task passed complex object, you can find more https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/airbnb_airflow/WhfoNC5xLOs

Comment: @Ted, I think after version 1.8.1 they suggest be specific about your start_date